# Creating a Base-UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance, user-controls

I've created several UserControls which got some common Properties. Is it possible to create a base-UserControl from which the concrete ones can derive?

Base Class:

```
public class LabeledControlBase : UserControl {
    public string ControlWidth {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ControlWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ControlWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ControlWidth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ControlWidth", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledControlBase), new PropertyMetadata("Auto"));
}
```

Concrete Class:

```
public partial class LabeledTextBox : Base.LabeledControlBase {
    public string LabelText {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LabelText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string TextBoxText {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextBoxTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextBoxTextProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TextBoxText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxText", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

What I want to achive:
I want to be able to set the "ControlWidth" Property on any UserControl which derives from "LabeledControlBase".

What is the problem:
The way I realized it my LabeledTextBox does not recognize GetValue and SetValue Methods although it inherits from LabeledControlBase which derives from UserControl. When changing Base.LabeledControlBase to UserControl everything works just fine (except I can not access my commonly used Properties).

Comment: does it give a compile time error? or just tells you in the editor that the method is not recognized?

Comment: as well in the error list as a compile time error. The errorlist says: 
Error CS0103 The name 'GetValue' does not exist in the current context ...

Comment: huh.. funny, I tried to replicate your problem and couldn't. In the Base.LabeledControlBase, the "Base." is the namespace for the LabeledControlBase correct?

Comment: that's correct. As mentioned when I replace LabeledControlBase with UserControl everything works just fine.

Comment: The partial `LabeledTextBox` class presumably has some XAML associated with it. What does it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I haven't seen `LabeledTextBox.xaml` I can't be sure, but I suspect your XAML is somehow wrong -- perhaps using `UserControl` as the root? The XAML should look something like this:

```
<wpf:LabeledControlBase
    x:Class="WPF.LabeledTextBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:WPF"
    x:Name="self"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=ControlWidth}" />
    </Grid>
</wpf:LabeledControlBase>
```

...with `LabeledControlBase` as the root. This lets me use a `LabeledTextBox` control in a page:

```
<wpf:LabeledTextBox ControlWidth="Hi" />
```

(`ControlWidth`'s intended semantics are likely not what I'm doing with it; this is just to verify that things work. And they do.)

Comment: That's it - I simply did something wrong within the XAML - Somehow I used my LabeledTextBox as the root (instead of my Base class) - now that I've changed that everything works just fine! Thanks.